# android out of memory exception after run several times

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I wrote an app with many activities.
After I run about 30 time (3 activities with database IO, setting images and so on) it will crash and logCat says "Out of memory on a 1036340-byte allocation."

I have no idea what object did not release from memory......

Can anyone tell me possible reason and solution?

Or how can I see what is in memory?

P.S. My Bitmap things is static in another activity, so it won't create everytime.

### Edit 1

To  user1779222:
   I thought it might be a solution for this problem so I tried to make it static. But it seem not helpful.

To Maharith Aditya S S:----------here is my logcat---------------

```
04-19 17:06:50.747: I/dalvikvm-heap(12439): Clamp target GC heap from 97.183MB to 96.000MB
04-19 17:06:50.747: D/dalvikvm(12439): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3853K, 8% free 91106K/98272K, paused 218ms, total 218ms
04-19 17:06:50.987: I/dalvikvm-heap(12439): Clamp target GC heap from 97.937MB to 96.000MB
04-19 17:06:50.987: D/dalvikvm(12439): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 194K, 7% free 91878K/98272K, paused 218ms, total 219ms
04-19 17:06:50.987: I/dalvikvm-heap(12439): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1036340-byte allocation
04-19 17:06:51.227: I/dalvikvm-heap(12439): Clamp target GC heap from 97.937MB to 96.000MB
04-19 17:06:51.227: D/dalvikvm(12439): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 7% free 91878K/98272K, paused 237ms, total 237ms
04-19 17:06:51.227: E/dalvikvm-heap(12439): Out of memory on a 1036340-byte allocation.
04-19 17:06:51.227: I/dalvikvm(12439): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
04-19 17:06:51.227: I/dalvikvm(12439):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ef0728 self=0x41edb600
04-19 17:06:51.227: I/dalvikvm(12439):   | sysTid=12439 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074143228
04-19 17:06:51.227: I/dalvikvm(12439):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=113289 stm=44410 core=0
04-19 17:06:51.237: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-19 17:06:51.237: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
04-19 17:06:51.237: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
04-19 17:06:51.237: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:816)
04-19 17:06:51.237: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2117)
04-19 17:06:51.247: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-19 17:06:51.247: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3545)
04-19 17:06:51.247: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:121)
04-19 17:06:51.247: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:117)
04-19 17:06:51.247: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-19 17:06:51.247: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-19 17:06:51.247: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
04-19 17:06:51.257: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at easylube.com.guardwatch.ActCheckHome.onCreate(ActCheckHome.java:338)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-19 17:06:51.277: I/dalvikvm(12439):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 17:06:51.277: D/skia(12439): --- decoder->decode returned false
04-19 17:06:51.277: D/AndroidRuntime(12439): Shutting down VM
04-19 17:06:51.277: W/dalvikvm(12439): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41eef8b0)
04-19 17:06:51.277: W/System.err(12439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{easylube.com.guardwatch/easylube.com.guardwatch.ActCheckHome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #260: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

### Edit 2

I use Bitmap for some ImageView and Others using .setBackgroundResource(Resource) .

My run step is: activityA->(A finish())activityB->(B finish())activityC->(C finish())activityA.........

I don't know will these info will help or not , I found a way to watch Heap,
it seems "data object"  may be the problem......

[image: first run]
[image: After 12 runs]

allocation tracker count stay about 512
[image]

System Infomation / memery Usage   Unknow increase from 3/4 to
[image]

To Rahul Kumar :

```
settingImg() {
  if(something){
      bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),R.drawable.img1);
      img.setBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, scaledwidth, scaledhight, false));
  }else if(something2){
      bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),R.drawable.img2);
      img.setBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, scaledwidth, scaledhight, false));
  }.........
}
swichActivity(){
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(B.this, C.class);
  intent .setFlags(intent .getFlags() | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  startActivity(intent);
  bmp.recycle();
  bmp=null;
  finish();


}
```

And my Image Size = 506*506  90.9KB

### Edit3

I just wrote an app with only 2 Activity and 2layout with only 1 TextView each.
And the memory usage is still  increase but slowly, after a long time,it crashed with same problem.

Why????

Comment: Post the Logcat.

Comment: check the image size and resolution...

Comment: Making your bitmaps static is not a good practise

Comment: post your code and bitmap size

Comment: Use a proper image loading library. There's at least 5 major ones for Android

Answer (score 0):

Use `Picasso` or `Glide` to load images, it will handle memory for you. Also will resize to fit bitmap size to your `ImageView`.